# Android Amazon In-App Billing - Verifying/Confirming Licences

Tags: android, billing, amazon-appstore

I have a fairly simply In-App Purchase setup - he user can buy a one-time licence to disable Ads and that's it, no subscriptions, no consumables - just a one-off licence they keep forever.

Obvious I want that to be forever INCLUDING after an uninstall/reinstall - and the latest Google Billing (v3) has the ability to check for the existence of the licence on startup and thus refresh the licence after an uninstall (and indeed, cancel it after a refund) but Amazon does not appear to support any re-querying of the status of a purchase!?

The only way I can find is to redo the purchase - at which point it will say "Oh, you've already bought this" and I can pick that up and give them the license back - but it's not automatic, they have to 'buy' it again to find out they own it and it would never know about refunds...

Anyone worked with the Amazon Billing API enough to understand whether this is possible?  The documentation is - frankly - poor (and often out-of-date), the forums are ghost-towns and when they do reply, it tends to be unhelpful - and their own example is woefully basic and does nothing like this at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this website, https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing/documentation/developer-guide.html, it seems like that you have to call `initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequest`, and 
`onPurchaseUpdatesResponse(PurchaseUpdatesResponse purchaseUpdatesResponse)` will in turn be called. the information in purchaseupdatesresponse should have what you need

Comment: I had wondered about that but there's a lack of "what does this actually do" in those instructions - I guess the disclaimer that you shouldn't rely on that mechanism is a suggestion that it's what I'm looking for - but surely you'd want to check that a licence still exists at least once per run (assuming the device is online!?)

Comment: AHA - in the API docs it says this

"A good use of this operation is to invoke it once per application run to make sure your view of ownership is consistent across devices."

WHich is exactly what I'm wanting it for and so that's a winner - I'll accept the answer as soon as it's possible to do so - thanks CChi!